# what is wrong with my codoing to get end result in myfile.txt

Tags: c#

I'm trying to get the answer on a txt file , so what I'm doing is multiplying a number x 2 , so if i type 1 the text file should show 2 , if i do 2 it should show 4 ... etc . But once I run the program and type the number I check the txt file and it comes out as 0

I had changed x=int.parse to convert.toint32 because i receive a null error

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

class program
{
    static void Main()
    {

        int num;   
        int x; 

        Console.Write("Enter a number 1-10 :");
        num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); 
        using (TextReader reader = File.OpenText("Myfile.txt"))  
       {
            x = Convert.ToInt32(reader.ReadLine());    

            //Console.WriteLine("nye : {0}",x);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)    
        {

            x = x * 2;   



        }
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("myfile.txt"))  
        {
            sw.Write(x);    // write it to the file

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem could lies here (assuming your file is empty to start with).

```
x = Convert.ToInt32(reader.ReadLine());
```

At first your output file is empty. So this line would give a value 0. After this, you multiple x with 2.

```
 x = x * 2;
```

In the loop, you are multiplying x with 0, which will always result in 0, which is the value you are writing back.

btw, What is unclear is siginificance of "num" and what is "n" used in the loop.

If I understood you correctly, you want to read a number from user and write 2*number in to a file.

If that is your requirement, reading the file in the first part is not needed. You could just do the following.

```
 Console.Write("Enter a number 1-10 :");
 var  num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); 
 using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("myfile.txt"))  
 {
    sw.Write(num * 2);    

 }
```